# Blank data inserted into MYSQL database with iOS frontend

Tags: php, mysql, ios

I'm creating an app which requires to insert a row into a mysql database (hosted online) however whenever i try to insert the data, the data is blank. there is nothing wrong with the php as my web front end works perfectly with the php script.

```
NSString *user = self.registerUsername.text;
NSString *password = self.registerPassword.text;
NSString *email = self.registerEmail.text;
NSString *model = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] model]];
NSString *sysVer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]];

NSString *connectionURL = @"mydomain.com/Register.php";
NSLog(@"%@", connectionURL);
//this is logged correctly

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:connectionURL]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *insert = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@&email=%@&model=%@&sysver=%@", user, password, email, model, sysVer];

NSLog(@"%@", insert);
[request setHTTPBody:[insert dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
//This is also logged correctly, giving me the right format i would expect

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request                             returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString *responseString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[responseData bytes]];
NSLog(@"%@", responseString);
//The response string is also correct, but no data is inserted into the database

NSString *success = @"success";
[success dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)responseString.length);
NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)success.length);
```

mRegister.php

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

include("config/dp.php"); //<- db connection

$con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","user","pass");
if(! $con)
{
die('Connection Failed'.mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("hk", $con);

$message = "";

$username = ($_POST['username']); 
$password = ($_POST['password']);
$email = ($_POST['email']);
$model = ($_POST['model']);
$sysver = ($_POST['sysver']);

$submit = $_POST["registerform"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO members (`username`, `password`, `email`, `model`, `sysver`) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email', '$model', '$sysver')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if ($result) { $message = "success"; }
else { $message = "failed"; }

echo utf8_encode($message);

?>
```

also, `responseString` usually shows up with some weird characters after it therefore affect the `responseString.length` value. Is there something wrong with my code or is it to do with my php?

Comment: You say insert online,shouldn't the connection be to the server and not to localhost?

Comment: that is just because i didn't want to but the server's ip up - it is different and works (which i can verify)

Comment: Edit your post to include the missing column so other wont say the same thing.

Comment: @Mihai updated to remove typos etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe PHP is not parsing the request body because you haven't set the `Content-Type` request header:

```
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

On the other hand I recommend you to use an HTTP library of iOS such as [AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.com) so you don't have to worry about generating the request body by hand. Check out [its documentation](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/).